# Application rejected due to 8.5: Use of protected 3rd party material

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have developed a lyrics finder application, spent more than a month adding and organising them in a database, yesterday, Apple review team rejected my app due to use of protected 3rd party material.

> The use of materials copyrighted by a third party requires documented
>   evidence of your right to use such content in your application.

What should I do in that case, should I contact every artist telling him if I can add his songs lyrics in my app?!?! What do they mean by `documented evidence`? I feel that they're requesting an infeasible thing. I can't accept that all that effort made during more than a month is vanished!
Do you faced such rejection before? And is there a feasible thing to do?
Here is 2 screenshots of the app(sent/chosen by Apple review team):

[image]

[image]

And what about this one:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lyrics-lite-lyricfind/id310626563?mt=8
And that one:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lyrics+/id376969803?mt=8

Isn't a misjudgment ?!

Comment: What was the final outcome?  Did you ever get this approved?

Comment: @SoldierOfFortan: They told me that I have to show the lyrics outside the app, meaning that I launch a web page in Safari. A very bad solution ...

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I am in a similar situation myself (just with a different type of content).  Will let you know if I am able to get approved.

Comment: Yep ,that's a good idea, to know about Apple "philosophy" in reviewing apps. Thanks :) ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a quick look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyrics#Copyright_and_royalties) reveals that you need a license for publishing them:

> Currently, there are many websites featuring song lyrics. This
>   offering, however, is controversial, since some sites include
>   copyrighted lyrics offered without the holder's permission. The U.S.
>   Music Publishers' Association (MPA), which represents sheet music
>   companies, launched a legal campaign against such websites in December
>   2005, the MPA's president, Lauren Keiser, said the free lyrics web
>   sites are "completely illegal" and wanted some website operators
>   jailed.

So this is not a misjudgement from Apple, they even protect you in some way from being sued by a random law company (for using copyrighted material without permission).

Regarding other lyrics apps on the AppStore: I assume they have a license. At least `LyricFind` does, as you could obtain a license for publishing lyrics from them.

Comment: But what do they mean by `holder's permission`! Should I contact Eminem or John Lennon to allow me to add their songs lyrics to my app?! Plus, what about this apps: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lyrics-lite-lyricfind/id310626563?mt=8,  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lyrics+/id376969803?mt=8

Comment: Regarding other apps: see my edited answer. You should not directly contact the artist, but obtain a license from a company, e.g. LyricFind or Gracenote.

Comment: I guess that we have to pay them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they won't give a license for free, yes.

Comment: I'm really disappointed to see all my work JUST vanished! Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: This won't help much, but: you should have done some research before even starting the project.

Comment: I REALLY DID NOT expected that they'll reject an app that it shows some text(lyrics) of some artists. I did not put some mp3 songs or videos whatever "sensitive".

Comment: For the use of any copyrighted material, including mp3 songs or song lyrics, you may need to consult an attorney specializing in copyright law and licensing procedures to determine what is needed to be done in your jurisdiction to be legal.  It's a big business.

Comment: This hurdle would have been extremely obvious if you had done some research prior to developing an application which features art that someone else created.